# Undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass - Ruby tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been looking for the same problem but not found it.

I'm following this [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html), and I'm stuck on setting validations for the text field.

Model (article.rb):

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }
end
```

Controller:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController:

    def new
      @article = Article.new
    end

    def create
      @article = Article.new(article_params)

      if @article.save
        redirect_to @article
      else
        render 'new'
      end
    end

    private
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
    end
```

View (new.html.erb):

```
<%= form_for :article, url: articles_path do |f| %>

  <% if @article.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>
        <%= pluralize(@article.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this article from being saved:
      </h2>
      <ul>
        <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>

<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
```

And when I try to add a new article I open `http://localhost:3000/articles/new` but instead of the form I see error `undefined method errors' for nil:NilClass` because of the error in this line `<% if @article.errors.any? %>`

What am I missing here. Looks like `@article` is being validated before created? How can I fix it?

index.html.erb:

```
<h1>Listing articles</h1>

<%= link_to "New article", new_article_path %>

<table>
 <tr>
   <th>Title</th>
   <th>Text</th>
 </tr>

 <% @articles.each do |article| %>
   <tr>
     <td><%= article.title %></td>
     <td><%= article.text %></td>
   </tr>
 <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: Is colon after ApplicationController is a typo?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call:

`<%= form_for @article, url: articles_path do |f| %>`

In the first line of new.html.erb

Answer (score 0):

Change the `form_for` to

```
<%= form_for(@article) do |f| %>

  <% if @article.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>
        <%= pluralize(@article.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
   this article from being saved:
      </h2>
      <ul>
        <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  ........
<% end %>
```

articles_controller.rb

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  ....
end
```

Comment: i changed it. Now i get this error: Showing:  blog/app/views/articles/index.html.erb     where line #11 raised:

undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Comment: I don't see an index action in your controller. Can you try adding an index action which has something like `@articles = Article.all`

Comment: ok i did it.... now another error appear: First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty ?

Comment: in new.html.erb i have : <%= form_for(@article) do |f| %>

Comment: Ok i did it... it was my mistake ... i had def new 2 times and i just have to delete it :) thanks guys for help ;))